# one() firing more than one time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a one() event handler that should (I'm led to believe) fire the code once on click but then not execute it again after that one click. Here, it checks whether a class is visible and adds 10 to a variable if it is. The problem is however I can click on it multiple times and it keeps adding 10 to the variable.

Am I doing something wrong?

```
$('.cme-confirm').one( "click", function(event) {

    if ($(".this-correct")[0]){
       case1Score = case1Score + 10;
    }
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    console.log(case1Score);
});
```

Thanks in advance.

#### Edit

Thanks to Richard Cane who explained that it's because I have more than one element with the class name. Therefore it is firing more than once. I was going to give each element a unique class, however Ruben Seratte has fixed my issue below. Many thanks all for your help.

Comment: I can't replicate this issue: http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/23w685d7/

Comment: Me neither http://jsfiddle.net/cnhm7po7/ - can u create a fiddle with the issue? Is there a chance that you rerun the binding code again?

Comment: How many DOM elements do you have with class cme-confirm ???

Comment: Do you have multiple elements with the class ".cme-confirm"? If so, your function will run once for each of those elements.

Comment: I think it has something to do with using it on a class, if you have more than one instance of the class then it'll be called more than once. Do you have more than one instance of `.cme-confirm`?

Comment: Yes, I have ten instances of this class within the page. It's running on jQuery mobile page.

Comment: @user-a5567ffg Then you will have this function run once, 10 times

Comment: .one in the JQuery API: **Description**: _Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element per event type._

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help. I did not understand that part of the description.

Comment: Yeah it could be written better ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that you now why it's happening, instead of giving the elements unique classes, you can fix the issue if you stop listening the event after it's fired:

```
$('.cme-confirm').on( "click.myId", function(event) {
    jQuery('.cme-confirm').off("click.myId");

    if ($(".this-correct")[0]){
       case1Score = case1Score + 10;
    }
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    console.log(case1Score);
});
```

Comment: Thank you Ruben Serrate - this makes much more sense than creating unique classes. I will apply this to the rest of my code, also. You've been a great help.

Comment: `bind` is deprecated. You should use `on`.

Answer (score 2):

For clarity of the comments:

The issue is that .one() will execute once for each element of a class if the selector contains only a class. This is described in the JQuery API:

**.one( events [, data ], handler )**
**Description:** *Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element per event type.*

Specifically, if you have 10 elements on a page of the same class, .one() will execute 10 times.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a function to run once, you can try something like this, it isn't perfect, but it should work:

**EDIT** - Added fiddle

---

http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/p8u6apbs/

---

```
var runOnce = true;

$('.cme-confirm').on("click", function(event) {
    if(runOnce){
        if ($(".this-correct")[0]){
            case1Score = case1Score + 10;
        }
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        console.log(case1Score);
        runOnce = false;
    }
});
```

With jquery's .one():

Currently, your function is running your function once for every class element you have. So if you have 10 elements with the same class, it will run once, ten times (once on each element). So in other words:

{1} {2} {3}

I click on {1}, {1} cannot be clicked again, the function will not run